# How to edit properties of webpart on an App page

Tags: spfx

Since SPFx 1.8 was release there is new type of pages - App pages. There is no edit mode on these pages. How i can change webpart properties without switching page into article and back?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use the `Set-PnPWebPartProperty` powershell command.
(https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Commands/WebParts/SetWebPartProperty.cs)

Or, you could - like you said - change it to Article and back, and only publish your changes *after* modifying the properties. This way visitors will never see the "article page" version

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm looking for something I can do right from webpart code without switching page type

Comment: @SergeyAslanov you can use the PnPJS library to manipulate the page and webpart properties. https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Client-side-Pages